# paysafe internal error ErrorCode1007

Tags: php, payment-gateway, paysafe

I'm trying to use PaySafe Rest API Via php Curl (mycurl) but i'm getting error.
my php code:

```
$url="https://api.test.paysafe.com/cardpayments/v1/accounts/xxxxxxx/auths";// si erreur ajouter HTTP/1.1
$headers=array('content-type: application/json');
$call_api=new mycurl($url);
$call_api->useAuth(true);
$call_api->setName(" my username");
$call_api->setPass("my password");
$call_api->setHeaders($headers);
$curlopt_postfields=json_encode( array(
    'merchantRefNum' => 'merchant ref',
    'amount' => 10,
    'settleWithAuth'=>true,
    'card' => array(
        'paymentToken' => 'my token key' 
    ),
    'billingDetails' => array(
        'street' => '100 Queen Street West',
        'city' => 'Toronto',
        'state' => 'ON',
        'country' => 'CA',
        'zip' => 'M5H 2N2'
    )
));
$call_api->setPost($curlopt_postfields);
$call_api->setJson();
$call_api->createCurl($url);
//result
$result_api_httpStatus=$call_api->getHttpStatus();
$result_api=$call_api->tostring();
if($result_api_httpStatus==200)
{
    echo 'OK';
}
else {
    //echo $result_api_httpStatus;
    print_r($result_api);
}
```

this process is explained [here](https://developer.paysafe.com/en/sdks/paysafejs/card-payment-with-token/)

And bellow, the returned error:

```
{"links":[{"rel":"self","href":"https:\/\/api.test.paysafe.com\/cardpayments\/v1\/accounts\/xxxxxx\/auths\/yyyyyyyyyy"}],"id":"yyyyyyyyyy","merchantRefNum":"merchant number","error":{"code":"1007","message":"Internal Error.","links":[{"rel":"errorinfo","href":"https:\/\/developer.paysafe.com\/en\/rest-api\/cards\/test-and-go-live\/card-errors\/#ErrorCode1007"}]},"settleWithAuth":true}
```

"message":"Internal Error." but i don't know why...

I remember that I followed the tokenize process of paysafe.js to generate the token as explained [here](https://developer.paysafe.com/en/sdks/paysafejs/overview/)

Help me please

Comment: Please share your test account number. It's perhaps due to a bug when you registered for a sandbox environment.

Comment: resolved, there was an problem on my account, Paysafe Support fixed it. Thanks

Comment: I got the same problem. 
I've been told for weeks was our fault. Glad someone else have this and found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

resolved, there was an problem on my account, Paysafe Support fixed it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my case, Paysafe didnt solve for me. But after several days they point me to the issue.

In my case when using the Authentication, I used wrongly the parameter "deviceChannel".
Solved setting deviceChannel=Browser